# d3js: Texts of different bubbles are getting overlapped in bubble-chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, bubble-chart

I have a graph as shown below:
[image]

Each bubble has some text with it and I also show a tipsy on hovering the bubble. As you can see, bubbles which have similar X and Y values are overlapping and thus the text of each bubble are getting mixed up so much that nothing is readable(Notice two red bubbles at Y:10-12 and X:30-35). I want to solve this issue, such that may be only one text is visible or both are visible in some way(if both are possible then this is preferred).   Also, I have very less data in this graph. The data can vary a lot and thus I might have many bubbles in a very small range. 
Is there any way to solve this issue?

Comment: Use a force simulation for the texts, setting the positions with `forceX/Y` and avoiding the overlap with `forceCollide`.

Comment: Also, I suggest you to change the domain of the x scale, those bubbles over the y axis are visually unpleasant.

Comment: The link has my script: http://jsfiddle.net/mjdctjkb/
I changed x and y values for texts but it is giving error saying "cannot read property "length" of undefined" when I use d3.forceX. Isn't this what I need to do?

Comment: Well, I'm not really understanding your comment...

Comment: And I don't understand where should I use forceCollide?

Comment: Now I see it in your code... it's not as simple as that. Please google "d3 force simulation" to understand what is a force simulation. After that, look for some tutorials on how to apply a force simulation to avoid overlapping.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158129/discussion-between-yesha-and-gerardo-furtado).