# Force simulation of bubbles and texts going unbounded and inconsistent with XY axis

Tags: javascript, d3.js, force-layout, bubble-chart

I have a d3 script given at this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ngfoha56/8/

The problem that I am facing is, as number of bubbles having same or similar X-axis value are increasing, the bubbles are going beyond 100(wrt X-axis) and are even getting cut down from sides or are becoming unbounded. Like in the given example, G, H, I and J all have same X and Y values but appear at different positions wrt X and Y-Axis and 'I' is getting cut from sides. I want keep the bubbles consistent with X-axis and Y-axis and keep them bounded.

How do I do that?

I even tried doing

```
 circles.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x = Math.max(radius, Math.min(width - radius, d.x)); })
 .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y = Math.max(radius, Math.min(height - radius, d.y)); });
```

as mentioned at this link: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1129492

to keep the bubbles within the height and width mentioned but did not work.

Comment: I already told you twice (in your last questions, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47094528/5768908) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47074763/5768908)), this is the last time: why are you using the force with the circles? If this is a scatter plot, the **precise position** of the circles is very important. You have to use the force with the **texts only**, not with the circles.

Comment: If I use force with only texts, then the circles will get overlapped like in this fiddle that you had provided: https://jsfiddle.net/02heuL98/
I want both circles and texts to be non-overlapping, bounded and consistent with XY axis

Comment: So, this is not a scatter plot, and you are simply *"lying with data"*. I strongly suggest you don't do that. If the circles overlap, choose another data representation: a bar chart, a slope chart, whatever. But don't use a force directed chart with axes: it simply makes **no** sense.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is most of the pointsare close to 100 and so the center of the circle will be close to 100 thus the circle will lie out.

One way could be, give a threshold of 90% which means points outside 90% will be made 90% of thier value, so display wise it will show up at 90% of its current value, thus the pont will not appear to go out of the scale.

```
    var percent =0.90;//changeit as per your conveninece
    simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
    .force("x", d3.forceX(function(d) {
    var k = parseInt((xscale(+d.student_percentile)/width)*100);
    if (k > percent*100){//if less than percent
        return xscale(+d.student_percentile * percent)//reduce the percentile
    }
        return xscale(+d.student_percentile);
    }))
    .force("y", d3.forceY(function(d) {
    var k = parseInt((yscale(+d.rank)/height)*100);
    if (k > percent*100){
        return yscale(+d.rank * percent)
    }

        return yscale(+d.rank);
    }))
    .force("collide", d3.forceCollide(20));
```

working code [*here*](https://jsfiddle.net/07op7ad4/)

Comment: Thank you for your solution. The bubbles are now bounded but they are still inconsistent wrt XY axis. Like 'H' is appearing somewhere near 80(wrt X-axis) but should be between 90-100(has X-axis of 95.19, scaled up) but 'I' having same parameters appears at almost the correct place.

Comment: yeah the problem is that since its a circle once you make it bounded.
If your circle indicates a point on x which is close to max it will appear as if its more than the max. This is becauseof its radius